# Issue with inserting data into SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I want o insert bulk data in SQL Express server using PHP.

I have a csv file containing data.

I am using below code to insert data but it just adds 50 rows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Upload page</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background: #E3F4FC;
 font: normal 14px/30px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #2b2b2b;
}
a {
 color:#898989;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
 color:#CC0033;
}

h1 {
 font: bold 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #CC0033;
}
h2 {
 font: bold 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #898989;
}
#container {
 background: #CCC;
 margin: 100px auto;
 width: 945px;
}
#form    {padding: 20px 150px;}
#form input     {margin-bottom: 20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="form">

<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '180');



//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
  echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
  echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
  
  //readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
 }

 //Import uploaded file to Database
 $row = 1;
 if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        $server = "10.10.10.10\SQLEXPRESS,1433";
  $options = array(  "UID" => "user",  "PWD" => "1234",  "Database" => "Analytics");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);
  if ($conn == false) die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));echo "Successfully connected!";
   $import="INSERT into [Table](column1,column2,column3) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
   echo $import;
    sqlsrv_query($conn,$import) or die(sqlsrv_error());
    unset($data);
     }
     fclose($handle);
 }
 echo "<br /></p>\n";
 echo $row;


 

 print "Import done";

 //view upload form
}else {

 print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

 print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='Main.php' method='post'>";

 print "File name to import:<br />\n";

 print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

 print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}

?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I print the result in php by commenting insert into command it will show all fields.

Comment: Are there any primary keys on your `Table`? Is there any single quotes in `data[0],data[1],data[2]`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing your maximum execution time ? That could be causing the issue.

[this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) page will probably help